# Imroving the javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code to calculate power of a number, The code is working fine for me but i am not sure if it is good performance wise.

```
<html>
  <head>
<SCRIPT>
function power(){
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var power = document.getElementById("power").value;
  var newNumber = number;
  for(var i=0; i<(power-1);i++){
    newNumber *= number;
  }  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= newNumber;
}
</SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id ="number" placeholder="Enter number">
    <input type="text" id ="power" placeholder="Enter power"> 
    <input type="submit" onclick = "power()">
    <p id ="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have changed my code to this -

```
  function power(){
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var power = document.getElementById("power").value;
    number = Math.pow(number,power)
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= number;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Math.pow(base, exponent)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow):

> The `Math.pow()` function returns the base to the exponent Power,  that
>   is, baseexponent.

Comment: But for that i need to declare my variables number and power outside my function and that is not a good practise.

Comment: Eh, no you don't: `var newNumber = Math.pow(number, power);`

Answer (score 2):

I have to point out, that your solution using the for-loop only works when power is a positive integer. It returns a wrong value for all non-integer powers and when power < 1. That is why using Math.pow() is a wise choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, if you dont want to use Math.pow is "optimized" you can't get better performance without using Math.pow.

Comment: Yes that was my question, Thanks